# How to create raster stack from multiple PRISM .bil rasters with for loop?

Tags: r, prism, raster

I have 37 rasters for annual PRISM climate data in one folder, but have not found a simpler way to load the rasters into R other than manually one at a time.

I have tried using this for loop to load the rasters and combine them into one data frame:

create stack

```
mystack <- pd_stack(prism_archive_subset("ppt","annual", years = 1982:2019))
```

Create data frame for the loop to stack all raster together.

```
filenames <- list.files(path = "./ppt rasters", pattern= '.bil', all.files=TRUE)
filenames

ncols <- dim(precip1982)[1]
nrows <- dim(precip1982)[2]

rasters <- stack(list(filenames))
```

initialize large object

```
final.df <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow = nrows, ncol = ncols)) 
counter=1
```

for loop through all files

```
for (file in filenames){
r <- raster(filenames)
test <- as.data.frame(r, na.rm=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, col.names=FALSE)
names(test)<- c(substring(file, 24, 29))
final.df <- cbind(z, test)
}

final.df[counter-1:nrow(final.df),]<-NULL
```

I get errors saying that the .local(.object...) : with other errors.

Is there a better way to set up the loop so it runs? Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question. Can you explain better what you are trying to do, what works and what does not? And use example data (see ?stack).

Answer (score 0):

`prism::pd_stack()` returns a `raster::RasterStack` object, so you need to use raster's `as.data.frame()` method on each layer.

You may want to crop/trim the data first. In my test for only 2 years of prism data it took ~3 minutes to create a 1.3GB data frame from the RasterStack.

```
library(prism)

# get 2 years of precip data as example
get_prism_annual("ppt", 2018:2019)

# get all the precip data from the prism archive as a RasterStack
# note that prism_archive_subset() will only return the 2018 and 2019 data
# if that is all that exists
mystack <- pd_stack(prism_archive_subset("ppt","annual", years = 1982:2019))

# now convert to data frame (each layer in the RasterStack is a Raster)
df <- lapply(mystack, as.data.frame)
```